# UIAnimator message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone

I am getting crazy:

```
*** -[UIAnimator removeAnimationsForTarget:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5ba13d0
```

It happens in different moments, when I scroll my tableview, when I switch my filter (a UISegmentedControl).

How can I fix it?

Comment: We need more code.  Also, try a build and analyze on teh project and see if that points to anything.

Comment: It looks like when perform any action, removeAnimationsForTarget method call on a deallocated object.can you find out which location it happens.

Comment: I would start by [searching previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sent+to+deallocated+instance), this is a common problem and the solutions are the same.

Comment: @Stefan H I don't use UIAnimator. Never. This is the reason because I'm getting crazy.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the same problem.
I thought it was related to UIAnimation, but it was related to UITableViewCell, instead.
I found a good starting point looking at this article.

http://marius.me.uk/blog/2011/mar/fixing-uianimator-removeanimationsfortarget-crash/

Good luck and let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptom (crash caused by `[UIAnimator removeAnimationsForTarget:]` message being sent to deallocated UITableViewCell, but it turned out to have been caused by a reason different from the one cited in the above solution. It turned out that the reason was that my UI was being updated by a non-UI thread. Specifically, I was calling `popViewController:animated:` from a background thread. When I moved this invocation to the UI thread via a callback the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Both **@er0** and **@notme**'s answers are right.

When I made two different Cell UI in storyBoard and tried to use them in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` it gave me this error on a completely different button action. That method is not related to UITableViewCell in any way (AFAIK).

First I used **@er0**'s way: on the method I was getting the crash, performed it in main thread.

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone
```

It solved the crash.

Then I came to realize my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` code needs to be refactored. In some special situation I was using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` two times for a single `indexPath`. Refactored the code and placed the if-else in a way that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is not called twice for a single indexPath. It solved my crash and I don't need the `performSelectorOnMainThread"` any more.

I ended up using **notme**'s solution.